# Alguien sabe como soluciono este codigo PHP me marca syntax error pero yo no le veo el error me pueden ayudar uso visual estudio code como edito?

Tags: php

```
<?php 

    $a = array("alvaro","bartolomeo","jose","jesus","pablo","manuel","ana","sofia","jorge",
             "sebastian","santiago","david","cristian","maria","martin");

    $name = $_REQUEST["name"]; // resive la respuesta del input 
    $sugerencia = "";

    if ($name !== "") {
        $lon = strlen($name); // el largo de la cadena 
        $name = strtolower($name) // convierte la cadena a minúscula

        foreach ($a as $valor => $names){
            # code...
            if(stristr($name, substr($names, 0, $lon))){ // si coincide la cadena con algún elemento de $a
                if($sugerencia == ""){
                    $sugerencia = $names
                }else{
                    $sugerencia = "$sugerencia, $names"
                };
            };
        };
    };

    echo $sugerencia === "" ? "no hay sugerencias" : $sugerencia;

?>
```

Comment: Te faltan varios punto y coma ";". Deberías poner el error que te pone y formatear correctamente el código

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que quieres devolver un listado para un autocompletado sin usar una base de datos.

Siguiendo con el código que has puesto:

```
<?php 

    $nombres = array("alvaro","bartolomeo","jose","jesus","pablo","manuel","ana","sofia","jorge",
             "sebastian","santiago","david","cristian","maria","martin");

    $valorBuscado = array_key_exists('name', $_REQUEST)? $_REQUEST["name"] : ''; // recibe la respuesta del input, comprobando que name está definido
    $sugerencias = [];

    if (!empty($valorBuscado)) {
        $valorBuscado = strtolower($valorBuscado); // convierte la cadena a minúscula

        foreach ($nombres as $nombre){
            if(mb_strpos($nombre, $valorBuscado) !== false){ // devuelve la posición donde empieza $buscado en la cadena $nombre. Devuelve false si no está
                    $sugerencias[] = $nombre;
            }
        }
    }

    echo empty($sugerencias)? "no hay sugerencias" : implode(', ', $sugerencias); //implode une todos los elementos del array poniendo la cadena pasada entre los elementos
```

He añadido comentarios donde he creído oportuno. También he puesto todas las variables en español ya que me ha parecido que es como te sientes más cómodo. Además, he renombrado algunas para que se entienda mejor su sentido.

Como te han indicado en otra respuesta, los if y foreach no llevan ";" al final.

Comment: Muchas gracias David , todavia soy un poco novato